# How to peoplecode with radio button

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Anyone of you who knows how to peoplecode with the value choosen with radio button?

I have this page with radio button of academic programs and when a user select from one of the programs, I want to print a report basing on that program chosen in the radio button.

Any idea where to start and how to do this?

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the page in Application Designer and check the properties of the radio button fields.

They will look something like this:
[image: Radio button properties]

All the related radio buttons will have the same record and field, but a different value.

To execute code, based on the selected radio button, you would evaluate the value:

```
Evaluate RECORD.FIELD.Value
When "VAL1"
     RunReport1();
When "VAL2"
     RunReport2();
When-Other 
     /* Error */
End-Evaluate;
```

Note: Fields used for radio buttons have to have XLAT validation IIRC